# How can I model/simulate/test non-human vocal arrangements?

Tags: phonetics, non-human-language

In various world-building projects, I find myself running into the aggravating situation of having to create languages for non-humans using the human phonetic inventory. I would love nothing more than to create exciting, original phonetic inventories unique to my worlds, but I have absolutely no clue how to go about doing this. Is there a method in which I could simulate, for example, airflows through a structure and the resulting sounds? This question might be better suited to, say - the biology StackExchange, but I'm sure if I posted this there, then it would be better suited for here.